# Problems publishing a .NET 6 Maui application as MSIX package

Tags: .net, windows, maui, publish

I have a .NET Maui application that needs to be published as a Windows MSIX package. The solutions consists of several projects that are referenced. The application will not be published to the Microsoft Store for now. All other projects that are referenced are .NET 6 projects, just like the main project.

When trying to publish the application I get the following output:

```
...

1>Improper project configuration: WindowsPackageType is set to None, but PublishAppxPackage is set to true.
1>Improper project configuration: WindowsPackageType is set to None, but PublishAppxPackage is set to true.
1>Improper project configuration: WindowsPackageType is set to None, but PublishAppxPackage is set to true.
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish started at 9:16 AM and took 08,418 seconds ==========
========== Package: 0 succeeded, 1 failed ===========
```

The package.appxmanifest file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
  xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
  xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
  xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap rescap">

    <Identity Name="maui-package-name-placeholder" Publisher="CN=ans" Version="0.0.2.0" />

    <mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="21E144AE-963F-4727-9EDC-7027D713AD04" PhonePublisherId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"/>

    <Properties>
        <DisplayName>$placeholder$</DisplayName>
        <PublisherDisplayName>User Name</PublisherDisplayName>
        <Logo>$placeholder$.png</Logo>
    </Properties>

    <Dependencies>
        <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.17763.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.19041.0" />
        <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.17763.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.19041.0" />
    </Dependencies>

    <Resources>
        <Resource Language="x-generate" />
    </Resources>

    <Applications>
        <Application Id="App" Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe" EntryPoint="$targetentrypoint$">
            <uap:VisualElements
              DisplayName="$placeholder$"
              Description="$placeholder$"
              Square150x150Logo="$placeholder$.png"
              Square44x44Logo="$placeholder$.png"
              BackgroundColor="transparent">
                <uap:DefaultTile Square71x71Logo="$placeholder$.png" Wide310x150Logo="$placeholder$.png" Square310x310Logo="$placeholder$.png" />
                <uap:SplashScreen Image="$placeholder$.png" />
            </uap:VisualElements>
        </Application>
    </Applications>

    <Capabilities>
        <rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust" />
    </Capabilities>

</Package>
```

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this problem?

I tried to publish the application as a project (As exe and not as MSIX package), which worked. However, the required resources are not published here, which is why, for example, the fonts are missing. Preferably the application should be published as MSIX package.

Comment: Using .NET 6 for MAUI is a mistake. People are fixing bugs on 8.0. Not everything is getting ported to 7.0, and almost nothing gets to 6.0.

Comment: Thanks, I try to migrate my Project to 7.0